# Powershell - formatted output in text file

Tags: powershell-3.0

i've a text file which has a number of records. i wanted to create another text file by taking portions of each line in the input file and creating colums values for (jurisdiction, count, filename and location) by picking those values as substrings of the record. for example below is the 1st 2 lines in the input file

010E 0001 Error Text C:\ftp\X1\2014-04-01\file1.txt

010E 0002 Error Text C:\ftp\X2\2014-04-02\file2.txt

I wanted to create a file with the columns(Jurisdiction, count, filename and location) with values X1,0001, file1,txt, C:\ftp\X1\2014-04-01\, then X2,0002,file2.txt,C:\ftp\X2\2014-04-02 and so on

i was able to create the script and create an output file with the above said way but its only that the values in the last column 'location' are getting truncated. Hence instead of C:\ftp\X1\2014-04-01, i'm getting C:\ftp\X1\2014-04... for all the values in this column

Below is the script which i used:

---

```
#input file location

$srcfile = 'C:\users\xxxxxx\desktop\File_Results.txt'

get-content $srcfile |select -property @{name="Jurisdiction";expression={$_.substring(28,2)}},@{name="Count";expression={$_.substring(6,4)}},@{name="File Name";expression={$_.substring(43)}},@{name="Location";expression={$_.substring(22,20)}}>test_result.txt;
```

---

Can someone please let me know how i can get the full path on the values in the 'location' column. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why limit the length that .substring() takes for 'Location'?  Why won't $_.substring(22) work?

Comment: i put the limit on the substring because i wanted only till the location portion 'C:\ftp\X1\2014-04-01' . if i put substring(22), it would go and fetch me the whole string till the end including the filename 'C:\ftp\X1\2014-04-01\file1.txt'

Comment: I adjusted your Select slightly, and got the results you expect.
Ran this in the ISE:
$t = get-content "C:\temp\src.txt" | select -property @{name="Jurisdiction";expression={$_.substring(28,2)}},@{name="Count";expression={$_.substring(6,4)}},@{name="File Name";expression={$_.substring(42)}},@{name="Location";expression={$_.substring(21,20)}}
No truncation of the path.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking that up. actually what i included in my question was just dummy records in the input file because i did not want to put any actual data in there. The solution which you suggested works perfectly when the location size is less. in the example i provided it is 'C:\ftp\X1\2014-04-01\file1.txt'. For this i dont see any truncation. But if the location is 'C:\data\ftpcopy\X1\2014-04-01\file1.txt', then the truncation is still there with the same solution which you provided. Hence i guess the length of the location matters. Can you please help out.

Comment: If the files exist, this should work: `select -property @{name="File Name";expression={((Get-Item -Path $_.substring(21)).Name)}},@{name="Location";expression={((Get-Item -Path $_.substring(21)).Directory)}} `   If the files don't exist, you could write functions to parse the filename and path from the string, and call those functions from the custom properties.